# How to display on an element-ui table data from other tables and display yes or no depending on an id

Tags: laravel, vue.js, element-ui, inertiajs

I'm trying to display in a table the infomation about a certain item in this case it's a question, information like what section it belongs to, which is the response type, and if the question is optional.

Right now I can only display the ids like `section_id`, `response_type_id` and `optional`. I want to display the names of the first two such as `section: school`, `response_type: text` and for the optional it's not an id for another table but a boolean, I want to display it like `optional: yes`.

If in my table I call `scope.row` to see what I have it's just the information about the question itself like

```
question
section_id
response_type_id
optional
```

This information is useful, but I want to use that to bring the name of the section and the type name for the response. In the optional I would like to be able to display yes or no instead of 1 or 0.

This is my controller code

```
public function index()
{
    return Inertia::render('Question/Index', [
        'survey_question' => SurveyQuestion::all(),
        'survey_section' => SurveySection::all(),
        'response_type' => ResponseType::all(),
        'options' => SurveyQuestionOption::all()
    ]);

}
```

If I look on Vue DevTools I can see those arrays full of data but I'm not sure how to access it.

This is my table

```
<el-table
    :data="survey_questions">
        <el-table-column
            prop="question"
            label="Pregunta">
        </el-table-column>
        <el-table-column
             prop="survey_section_id"
             label="Seccion">
        </el-table-column>
        <el-table-column
              prop="response_type_id"
              label="Tipo de Respuesta">
         </el-table-column>
         <el-table-column
              prop="optional"
              label="Opcional">
          </el-table-column>
</el-table>
```

If I change the prop to something like this nothing shows up, it's just empty or I get an error like this

```
<el-table-column
    label="Seccion">
        <template slot-scope="scope">
            <p> {{ scope.row.survey_section.title }} </p>
        </template>
</el-table-column>
```

```
Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `formatter` : https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table#table-column-attributes

In your code it would look something like that :

```
<el-table
    :data="survey_questions">
        <el-table-column
            prop="question"
            label="Pregunta">
        </el-table-column>
        <el-table-column
             prop="survey_section_id"
             label="Seccion"
             :formatter="surveyFormatter">
        </el-table-column>
        <el-table-column
              prop="response_type_id"
              label="Tipo de Respuesta">
         </el-table-column>
         <el-table-column
              prop="optional"
              label="Opcional"
              :formatter="optionalFormatter">
          </el-table-column>
</el-table>
```

```
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {...}
    },
    methods: {
      surveyFormatter(row, column, cellValue) {
        return row.survey_section.title;
      }, 
      optionalFormatter(row, column, cellValue) {
        return cellValue ? 'yes' : 'no';
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```